# Route restricting to that user and admin only

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to make user show their report only. Not authenticated user showing other users report. But, admin could show all users report.
I have this route:

```
Route::get('/showReport/{id}', 'CeciController@showReport');
```

I want this route to be accessed by only authenticated user which has that report id and the admins. If i put it in auth middleware group, authenticated user can acess others users report.`showReport/4`, `showReport/5`, `showReport/6`. And if i put it under admin middleware group. Even the authenticated user of that id can't acess it. How can this be acheived?

View:

`Report for the month <b> {{$report->month}}: </b> <a href="{{url('/showReport', [$report->id])}}">Show Report Details</a>`

Here is the controller:

```
public function showReport($id)
    {
        $report=Report::where('id',$id)->first();
        if($report)
        {
            return view('show_report')->with('report',$report);
        }      
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new middleware and check if the Authenticated user's id matches the given id parameter:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    # Allow only if the user is admin or id matches
    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($this->isAdmin($user) or ($request->input('id') === $user->id)) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but $request->id is the id of report which belongs to a user, not a user id actually.

Comment: and i got the user id using whereHas() the report id.

Comment: I'm always a champion of silly mistakes ;) Thanks for correcting it